# Mouse cursor having a longer trail and lagging

Tags: 16.04, kernel, graphics, 18.04, cursor

Xubuntu 16.04.4, Kernel: 4.13.0-42 x86_64, CPU: i3-4030U, Graphics: Intel HD 4400.

After kernel 4.13.0-40, my mouse cursor started to have a bigger trail then before, lagging and stutter during some load. During loading redhift mouse experience more lag.

On a kernel 4.13.0-39 and 4.13.0-41 all good.

I've tried to test on a various kernels and here are the results:
Xubuntu 16.04.4, Kernel 4.13.0-39 = Good
Xubuntu 16.04.4, Kernel 4.13.0-40 = Bad
Xubuntu 16.04.4, Kernel 4.13.0-41 = Good
Xubuntu 16.04.4, Kernel 4.13.0-42 = Bad
Xubuntu 16.04.4, Kernel 4.15.18(Ubuntu mainline) = Bad
Xubuntu 16.04.4, Kernel 4.16.4(Ubuntu mainline) = Bad
Ubuntu 18.04, Kernel 4.15 = Bad
Xubuntu 18.04, Kernel 4.16.10(Ubuntu mainline) = Bad
Xubuntu 18.04, Kernel 4.16.11(Ubuntu mainline) = Bad
Xubuntu 18.04, Kernel 4.16.12(Ubuntu mainline) = Bad
Fedora 28, Kernel 4.16.3 = Bad
OpenSuse Tumbleweed, Kernel 4.16.8 = Good
Manjaro 17.1.9 KDE, Kernel 4.9.96 = Good
Manjaro 17.1.9 KDE, Kernel 4.14.36 = Good
Manjaro 17.1.9 KDE, Kernel 4.16.4 = Good
Manjaro 17.1.9 KDE, Kernel 4.17.0-1 = Good

No one answering and I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same cause was referenced in these reports:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1773993
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1773581
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106943
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1773520
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=103497

Kernel 4.15.0-24 fixed the issue on Bionic and Xenial. The fix also available in the kernel 4.18-rc1 and will be backported to other Ubuntu kernels.